# Can't get the fields of the model which has many fields in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

My project uses Angular 5 and Typescript. 
I have got a problem with the model has many fields. When I submit the form, I can not have all the fields of the model. Some fields of the model have been lost. I do not know the reason why. Have anyone know what the problem with my code or tell me some suggestions, please?

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="bold">Name</lable>
        <input  type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="model.name" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label class="bold">Email</lable>
        <input  type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="model.email" />
    </div>  
    <!-- Many other fields -->
</div>
<button pButton type="button" (click)="onSave()" class="bg-blue-light btn-medium" label="Save"></button>
```

**Model:**

```
export class CustomerModel {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    // Many other fields: over 100 fields
}
```

**Component:**

```
// Init new model
public model: CustomerModel = new CustomerModel();

// Handle save event
public onSave() {
    let fields = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.model);
    // let fields = Object.keys(this.model);
    console.log(fields);
}
```

I have debugged with chrome, I saw that the model doesn't have enough fields, so both of function getOwnPropertyNames() and keys() don't have the result right. I guess that there is a problem with the model has many fields because I can get success with the model has some fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.model)`;

or `Object.keys(this.model)`; will only give you the properties which have the `values` set.

So, you will not see the `properties` in the list which are not yet initialized.

Check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ownpropertynames?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, Amit Chigadani. But why does the Chrome debugger also not know the existing of the fields of the model?

Comment: If the value is set to some property, in your case via an `ngModel`, then they will be definitely shown with `Object.keys()`.

Comment: See this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ownpropertynames?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Just type inside one of the elements and see the result on console.

Comment: Thanks again, the problem exactly as you answered above. But only one thing you are wrong, if I set the value with null or undefined, both functions also get the properties.

Comment: Ah, so the conclusion is, properties wont be listed if they are not yet initialized. I have updated the answer.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the great support.